# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I get this error and I don't know how to resolve it.

The stack trace :

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source] 
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable'1 source, Func'2
>   predicate) +4358562
>
> eCommerce.Services.BasketService.addToBasket(HttpContextBase
>   httpcontext, Int32 productid, Int32 quantity) in
>   E:\projects\C#\eCommerce\eCommerce.Services\BasketService.cs:51
>   eCommerce.WebUI.Controllers.HomeController.AddToBasket(Int32 id) in
>   E:\projects\C#\eCommerce\eCommerce.WebUI\Controllers\HomeController.cs:34

This is the code :

```
public bool addToBasket(HttpContextBase httpcontext, int productid, int quantity)
{
    bool success = true;

    Basket basket = GetBasket(httpcontext);

    // this line throws the error
    BasketItem item = basket.BasketItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductId == productid);

    if (item == null)
    {
        item = new BasketItem()
            {
                BasketId = basket.BasketId,
                ProductId = productid,
                Quantity = quantity
            };
        basket.BasketItems.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        item.Quantity = item.Quantity + quantity;
    }

    baskets.Commit();

    return success;
}
```

Please help me I have been stuck for a while now

Comment: Check that `BasketItems` is not `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing if `GetBasket()` always returns a value or not, I'll assume that it might not always return a value so we check for null. Also, `basket` might not be null but `BasketItems` might be so let's check if that object has any values.

If both conditions are true, then we go ahead and execute the rest of the code. If not, then we return `false`. You could also create a message here to log or return to the user about the basket being empty/null.

```
public bool addToBasket(HttpContextBase httpcontext, int productid, int quantity)
        {
            bool success = true;

            Basket basket = GetBasket(httpcontext);

            // Not sure if GetBasket always returns a value so checking for NULLs 
            if (basket != null && basket.BasketItems != null && basket.BasketItems.Any())
            {
                BasketItem item = basket.BasketItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProductId == productid);

                if (item == null)
                {
                    item = new BasketItem()
                    {
                        BasketId = basket.BasketId,
                        ProductId = productid,
                        Quantity = quantity
                    };
                    basket.BasketItems.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Quantity = item.Quantity + quantity;
                }

                baskets.Commit();

                success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Basket is null or BasketItems does not contain any items. 
                // You could return an error message specifying that if needed.
                success = false;
            }

            return success;
        }
```

Comment: stil didnot work i had the same error at that line `if (basket != null && basket.BasketItems.Any())`

Comment: You also need `&& basket.BasketItems != null`. Your error is because `BasketItems` is `null`

Comment: Updated the example above to also look for null on basket.BasketItems

Comment: Thank You  very MUCH IT Did Work :D

Answer (score 1):

Always check for null values when dereferencing.  Put in a check that GetBasket did not return a null, that basket.basketitems is not null before dereferencing it, etc.